# CSS Wrapper shifts upon navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation, uinavigationbar, wrapper

I have an issue in which every time I navigate to different pages the entire wrapper section of my site sometimes shifts left and right depending on what page you're on. If possible I'd like this so it always stays still no matter what page you navigate too. I'll provide a [snippet](http://gyazo.com/a6396ccae035fd9de030915151e6b8ff) of what I mean.

Here is my CSS for the entire styling of the website if it helps, if there's  any other code you may need such as html let me know and i can provide that as well.

```
/*CSS FOR ALL PAGES*/

/*BODY/WRAPPER SECTION*/

body {background:#EEEEEE;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;}

#wrapper {width: 1750px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 2px 0px;
          border: 1.5px solid #E0E0E0;
          color: #E0E0E0;}

/*TOP BANNER SECTION*/

#banner {height:150px;}

#logo {}

#ip_box {
         width:200px;
         height:43px;
         background:#212121;
         border-radius: 5px;
         box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;}

#ip_text {color: white;
          font-size: 15px;}

#teamspeak_box {width:159px;
                  height:43px;
                    background:#212121;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px;}

#teamspeak_box_2 {width:43px;
                   height:43px;
                   background:#313131;
                   border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;}

#teamspeak_text {color: white;}          


#teamspeak_image {}


/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/

* {margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;}

#nav_bar {background-color: #313131;
          height: 45px;
          text-align: center;}

#nav_bar ul {padding: 0;}

#nav_bar > ul > li {display: inline-block;}

#nav_bar ul > li > a {color: white;
                      display: block;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      font-weight: normal;
                      padding-left: 15px;
                      padding-right: 15px;
                      line-height: 45px;
                      transition: all 0.5s ease;}

#nav_bar ul li ul {display: none;
                   list-style: none;
                   position: absolute;
                   background: white;
                   margin-left:0px;
                   box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
                   text-align: left;
                   z-index:1;}

#nav_bar ul li a.active-page {background-color: #212121;}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {line-height: 2em;}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover {background: #212121;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a {color: #000000;
                        display: block;}

#nav_bar ul li ul li a:hover {background: #1565C0;
                              color: white;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}

/*BOTTOM FOOTER SECTION*/

#bottom_footer {width: 1750px;
                height: 50px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                margin-top: 15px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                background:white;
                border-radius: 5px;
                box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 2px 0px;
                border: 1.5px solid #E0E0E0;
                color: #E0E0E0;}

#created_by {padding: 17px;
             text-align: center;
             color:black;}

#social_media_youtube {float: left;
                       margin: -46px;
                       margin-left: 315px;}

#social_media_twitch {float: left;
                      margin: -43px;
                      margin-left: 380px;}

#social_media_twitter {float: right;
                       margin: -53px;
                       margin-right: 368px;}

#social_media_facebook {float: right;
                        margin: -47px;
                        margin-right: 325px;}

/*ELEMENT SELECTIONS SECTION*/

p {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   margin-left: 20px;
   margin-right: 20px;}

ul {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 37px;
    color:black;}

h3 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color:black;}

h4 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color:black;}
```

Comment: From the gif you provided, it sure looks like your page is responding to a scrollbar appearing on the right. No way to fix that unless you make all of the pages have a scrollbar with `min-height: 101%` or the like.

Comment: ahh right I see, thanks for the info, I'm new to web design and that so I don't see everything.

Comment: I'll just post it as the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pages aren't rendering any differently. The problem you are seeing is that a scrollbar is appearing in your window on some of the pages, causing the viewport to shrink by about 20px.

Nothing you can really do about this unless you make all of the pages be at least long enough to trigger the scroll bar, or short enough to not trigger the scrollbar.

<sub><sub>At least as far as I know...</sub></sub>